# Flex Shoutcast player

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I need a bit of help, I`m trying to find a way to play shoutcast though flex, with only a play and pause function.

I followed the steps in:
[Flex/Flash Shoutcast player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704121/flex-flash-shoutcast-player)

But found that the new Flex 4.6 is more updated than the code in the previous link.

Can someone please show me the right direction or code that can be used for playing a shoutcast stream?

Thanks!